# Check if a shell-executable program is running

Tags: shell, ubuntu

Is it possible in Ubuntu to check if the following shell-executable is running? The name of the executable is `ibgateway`. When I run `htop`, the command that I see is the following, which means it is currently running.

```
 /bin/sh -c nohup "/home/user1/Jts/ibgateway/978/ibgateway" "-J-DCHANNEL=latest" "-J-DchannelChanged=false" "-J-DjtsConfigDir=/home/user1/Jts" "-J-Drestart=jdapbbikegkmhgpnhhk
```

I have tried `pgrep ibgateway` but it does not return anything although `ibgateway` is running. I am looking for a way to check from terminal that the above process is running or not.

**UPDATE**

```
user1@SFO:~$ cat /proc/11965/comm
sh

user1@SFO:~$ cat /proc/11965/cmdline
/bin/sh-cnohup "/home/user1/Jts/ibgateway/978/ibgateway" "-J-DCHANNEL=latest" "-J-DchannelChanged=false" "-J-DjtsConfigDir=/home/user1/Jts" "-J-Drestart=jdapbbikegkmhgpnhhkpeglncdomifcjhpdimcbe"  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the code? That is not how `-c` works. When I run `/bin/sh -c nohup touch nohup` I get an error message from `nohup` (missing operands).

Comment: Yes. I copied the command from `htop`.

Comment: You are aware that what you type in a shell command line is not what you get in the process list (except for trivial cases without any shell features like quoting)? Run the command and see what happens.

Comment: Find out the PID of the process and add the output of `cat /proc/$PID/comm` and `cat /proc/$PID/cmdline` to your question.

Comment: Please see the updated question for the outputs for `cat /proc/$PID/comm` and `cat /proc/$PID/cmdline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command should be:

```
/bin/sh -c 'nohup "/home/user1/Jts/ibgateway/978/ibgateway" '\
'"-J-DCHANNEL=latest" "-J-DchannelChanged=false" '\
'"-J-DjtsConfigDir=/home/user1/Jts" '\
"-J-Drestart=jdapbbikegkmhgpnhhk"'
```

All the `"` are unnecessary as there are no special characters which they could protect. And at the end one is even missing.

### possible solutions

#### SystemD

The probably best way to handle this is to use SystemD. Create a unit file, start the service with `systemctl start ibgateway.service` and query its state with `systemctl status ibgateway.service`. No need for `sh`, no need for `nohup.

You do not even have to create a unit file, you can just use `systemd-run` (as non-root):

```
$ systemd-run --user ./testscript.sh
Running as unit: run-r1422e75c673a4439aaacefd0df118a51.service

$ systemctl --user status run-r1422e75c673a4439aaacefd0df118a51.service
● run-r1422e75c673a4439aaacefd0df118a51.service - /home/hl/tmp/./testscript.sh
     Loaded: loaded (/run/user/1000/systemd/transient/run-r1422e75c673a4439aaacefd0df118a51.service; transient)
  Transient: yes
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-08-08 02:36:57 CEST; 26s ago
   Main PID: 7740 (testscript.sh)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/run-r1422e75c673a4439aaacefd0df118a51.service
             ├─7740 /bin/bash /home/hl/tmp/./testscript.sh
             └─7742 sleep 100
```

**check run status**

The best approach seems to be:

```
$ systemctl show dracut-shutdown.service | grep -e ActiveState -e SubState       
ActiveState=active
SubState=exited

$ systemctl show display-manager.service | grep -e ActiveState -e SubState
ActiveState=active
SubState=running
```

So you could `grep` for `SubState=running` (and `ActiveState=active` for a clean solution).

Comment: Sorry that my question was not clear enough. Please see the updated version

Comment: @AFP The command line in my answer does result in the process list entry you put in your question.

Comment: How do you query the operating system whether it is running or not? I would like to use this in a Python script to return for example a true or false.

Comment: @AFP I added some information to the answer.